# How to get json from javax.ws.rs.client.Entity?

Tags: java

This sentence is giving me a 500 error on the server side and I would like to know what it sends in the post:

```
    res = target.request( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
     .header( "Token", token )
     .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
     .post( Entity.entity( req, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ) );
```

req is an Object and I would like to see the json that is generated when doing the "Entity.entity (req, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)".

Is there any way to see the JSON that is sent?

Comment: A 500 error is usually accompanied by an exception and a stack trace. What does it say?

Comment: In the res.getStatusInfo () it returns a " Internal Server Error", but if I make a request with postman, it works. That's why I want to know the json I send. Because I do not have it clear

Comment: In the tomcat I get the following error:  Insert Client received SOAP Fault from server: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@c110ee0

Comment: Ok, did you heed that suggestion about checking the server log for more detail?

Comment: The problem is the json format. But I do not know how to see it